# mule logging-interceptor With Spring AOP

Tags: mule

I am new to mule 3.2.1. I have implemented logging-interceptor on component level.

I am not satisfied with this, I want to implement logging for spring AOP. My mule flow I have written spring AOP configuration but not even calling my pointcut and my advice method.

Could you tell me how can I implement Spring AOP in Mule 3.2.1. while calling my component I want to log all the payloads.

Config/code snippets:

```
<!-- Spring AOP entries starts here -->
<bean id="advice" class="com.aop.IntegrationInterceptor" />
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="advice">
        <aop:pointcut id="fixedDepositDetails"
            expression="execution(* com.integration.impl.FixedDepositDetailsImpl.getFixedDepositDetails(..))" />
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="fixedDepositDetails" method="fixedDepositDetailsLogger" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

In mule-config.xml

```
<spring:import resource="classpath:mule_global_config.xml"/>
```

Code:

```
public FixedDepositDetails fixedDepositDetailsLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable
```

Comment: please could you tell me how can i implement spring aop in mule 3.2.1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is my config files                                                                               <!-- Spring AOP entries starts here -->
 <bean id="advice" class="com.aop.IntegrationInterceptor" />
 <aop:config>
  <aop:aspect ref="advice">
   <aop:pointcut id="fixedDepositDetails"
    expression="execution(* com.integration.impl.FixedDepositDetailsImpl.getFixedDepositDetails(..))" />
   <aop:around pointcut-ref="fixedDepositDetails" method="fixedDepositDetailsLogger" />
  </aop:aspect>
 </aop:config>

Comment: in mule config xml, i am calling this spring config xml.  <spring:import resource="classpath:mule_global_config.xml"/>. my java component is calling but my AOP component is not calling

Comment: public FixedDepositDetails fixedDepositDetailsLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable

Comment: Please do not post code in comments: I've updated your post for you. Other question: how do you use Spring beans in Mule? With `<component><spring-object>...`?

Answer (score 0):

I have issue related to to the following:

```
expression="execution(* com.integration.impl.FixedDepositDetailsImpl.getFixedDepositDetails(..))" />
```

and the way how Mule handle it you put

```
 expression="execution(public * *(..))" />
```